# ng-select displaying only old selected label while binding selected value dynamically in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, combobox, label, dropdown

I have created a common component for ng-select dropdown and I am using that component in all the forms. I have a scenario where I have multiple data rows in a table. I also have a form that contains textboxes, dropdowns (common component), and other controls. On table row selection I am displaying the data in form and it is working perfectly for all the dropdowns. The issue arises when I open a dropdown, close it without selecting anything, and then select another table row; the label in the ng-select dropdown remains the same, even though the value is changing in the background. Please suggest any solution if you faced this type of issue in the past. I am using ng-select version 7.4.0.

**Common component for dropdown(ng-select):**

```
<ng-select [items]="itemsBuffer"
           [virtualScroll]="virtualScroll"
           [bindLabel]="bindLabel"
           [bindValue]="bindValue"
           [placeholder]="placeholder"
           [loading]="loading"
           [editableSearchTerm]="editableSearchTerm"
           [selectOnTab]="selectOnTab"
               [addTag]="addCustomTag"
           [multiple]="multiple"
           [disabled]="disabled"
           [readonly]="readonly || loading"
           [class]="class"
           [name]="formControlName"
           [ngClass]="ngClass"
           [(ngModel)]="value"
           [markFirst]="true"
           (change)="onChange($event)"
           (blur)="OnBlur($event)"
           (keydown.tab)="onTab($event)"
           (focus)="onFocus($event)"
           (focusout)="onFocusout($event)"
           (keydown.enter)="onEnter($event)"
           [searchFn]="customSearchFn"           
           #ngSelect>
  <ng-template ng-header-tmp *ngIf="items||itemsBuffer">
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Loaded {{itemsBuffer.length}} of {{(virtualScroll) ? (items.length) : itemsBuffer.length}}</small>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-index="index" *ngIf="!optionTemplate">
    {{bindLabel?(item[bindLabel]==null?item[bindValue]:item[bindLabel]):item}}
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-index="index" *ngIf="optionTemplate">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="optionTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: item}">
    </ng-container>
  </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

**and I am using this component on other forms like below:**

```
<hofeng-combo-box [items]="slsMainList"
                  [loading]="slsPersonLoading"
                  virtualScroll="true"
                  bindLabel="DisplayProp"
                  bindValue="ValueProp"
                  placeholder="Select Sales Man"
                  formControlName="slsPersonFilterEdit">
</hofeng-combo-box>
```

I have searched over the web but none of them worked for me.